# Error running phonegap camera sample

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, camera

Hi I tried to run the [phonegap camera sample](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera) on my Sony Xperia E device. The app is launched in the device correctly, however when I hit the Capture Photo button I got and alert box says "Failed because: class not found". In the LogCat view in the eclipse I found these error logs:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher
W/System.err:   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
W/System.err:   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
W/System.err:   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
W/System.err:   at org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry.getClassByName(PluginEntry.java:117)
W/System.err:   at org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry.createPlugin(PluginEntry.java:93)
W/System.err:   at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:264)
W/System.err:   at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.execHelper(PluginManager.java:219)
W/System.err:   at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:214)
W/System.err:   at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:53)
W/System.err:   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeMouseClick(Native Method)
W/System.err:   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeMouseClick(Native Method)
W/System.err:   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$6700(WebViewCore.java:57)
W/System.err:   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.dispatchWebKitEvent(WebViewCore.java:1856)
W/System.err:   at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.dispatchWebKitEvent(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:689)
W/System.err:   at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.dispatchWebKitEvents(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:639)
W/System.err:   at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.access$800(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:78)
W/System.err:   at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher$WebKitHandler.handleMessage(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:1153)
W/System.err:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err:   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:827)
W/System.err:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cordova/CameraLauncher
W/System.err:   ... 21 more
W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher
W/System.err:   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
W/System.err:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
W/System.err:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
W/System.err:   ... 21 more
I/System.out: Error adding plugin org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher.
D/PluginManager: exec() call to unknown plugin: Camera
```

I strictly follow the documents and already added the following items in config.xml:

```
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
```

I've also running successfully this lines from my android-sdk folder:

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git
```

I've cleaned the project in eclipse several times and running it several times, all lead to the same result. Anyone has any idea where I was wrong?

thx...

PS

- **phonegap version: 3.0.0-0.14.4**
- **cordova version: 3.0.9**

The index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

// Wait for Cordova to connect with the device
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// Cordova is ready to be used!
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
    //alert(imageData);  

    // Get image handle
    //
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
    // Unhide image elements
    //
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';

    // Show the captured photo
    // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
    //
    smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    alert("inside large image")
    // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
    // console.log(imageURI);

   // Get image handle
   //
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
    largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhoto() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhotoEdit() {
  // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string  
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail,
    { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}


// Called if something bad happens.
// 
function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
<button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
<img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
<img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just checked this git(`git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git`) from the Camera API documentation and its `src/android/CameraLauncher.java` file's package name is `com.apache.cordova.camera` if your source code is also using this package name, then ur config file value should be changed to `org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher`

Comment: My phonegap version is 3.0.0-0.14.4, cordova version is 3.0.9. I think they are not using `plugins.xml` anymore. Following http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera, I added camera plugin into `config.xml`

Comment: when you type in "phonegap local plugin list", does your plugin appear on the list?

Comment: It shows T:\tmp\phonegapapp>phonegap local plugin list
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.camera
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.device
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.media-capture

Comment: hmm,,,It's weird that log message says your Camera plugin is unknown. Did you check your service name matches the one used in the JavaScript exec call?

Comment: I added the index.html source code to the question. It's all coming from the phonegap camera api document

Comment: I just checked this git(https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git) from the documentation above and its src/android/CameraLauncher.java file's package name is "com.apache.cordova.camera" if your source code is also using this package name, then ur config file value should be changed to "org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher".

Comment: Yep! changing the `org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher` to `org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher`fixed the problem! Thanks a lot, can you answer this question so that I can grant you the credential?

Comment: I edited my answer. Glad to hear that the problem is fixed :)

Comment: Worked for me as well. Is there a good place to file a bug for Phonegap?

Comment: I have changed the package in config.xml, but still can't overcome from this problem, i am using cordova-3.2.0, Pls help me...

Answer (score 1):

Change `org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher` to `org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher` in **config.xml**.

That worked for me.